# Add and find Dropdownlist at Runtime inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my asp.net application, I have used Gridview control, In which i have to add Dropdownlist at runtime for each cell.Which i am able to bind successfully.
Below is my code which inside row databound event,

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gdvLocation.Rows) {
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        for (int i = 1; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {
            var dlRouteType = new DropDownList();
            dlRouteType.ID = "ddlRouteType";
            dlRouteType.DataSource = GetRouteTypeList();
            dlRouteType.DataTextField = "RouteType";
            dlRouteType.DataValueField = "Id";
            dlRouteType.DataBind();
            row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(dlRouteType);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a button in my page, which has functionality to save data to database . While saving data i have to pass the value from Dropdownlist which i have added at runtime. On button click i am writing following code to get data from dropdownlist,

```
var ddlDropDown = (DropDownList)row.Cells[i].FindControl("ddlRouteType");
```

But i am getting null in ddlDropDown  object. I have even added Update panel inside aspx page. Any suggessions most welcome.
Thanks in advance
Sangeetha

Comment: You might be looking in wrong cell try using row.FindControl("ddlRouteType"); also make sure you do not rebind gridview on postback.

Comment: u are adding the ddl to every column in every row?

Comment: you should post the entire button click handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these errors in your code

1. RowDataBound already iterates through each rows and so all you need not write that `foreach` on top
2. You are iterating from index 1, index are zero-based. So start from zero.
3. The DropDownList ID must be unique, so better write something like,`dlRouteType.ID = "ddlRouteType_" + i;`

The code should be,

```
protected void gdvLocation_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //removed the foreach loop
    var row = e.Row;
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) //changed index
        {
            var dlRouteType = new DropDownList();
            dlRouteType.ID = "ddlRouteType_" + i; //gave unique id
            dlRouteType.DataSource = GetRouteTypeList();
            dlRouteType.DataTextField = "RouteType";
            dlRouteType.DataValueField = "Id";
            dlRouteType.DataBind();
            row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(dlRouteType);
        }
    }
}
```